# How to format postal code in SSRS Expression Builder

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to format a 9 digit postal code `##### - ####`, This is what i have at the moment, but it does not work.

```
IIf(Len(First(Fields!PostalCode.Value, "VesselCreditMemo"))>5,
      Format(First(Fields!PostalCode.Value, "VesselCreditMemo"),
       "00000-0000"),First(Fields!PostalCode.Value, "VesselCreditMemo")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
=mid(Fields!PostalCode.Value,1,5) &"-"& mid(Fields!PostalCode.Value,6,4)
```

In textbox expression.

Comment: Thank you! This worked great as well as the one above!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, depending on your data, you should modify regular expression, but usually it's done with something like this:

```
=System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(Fields!F1.Value, "(\d{5})(\d{4})", "$1-$2")
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked great as well as the one below!!